# How to avoid " already defined in " caused by a 3rd party lib?

Tags: c++, build, libraries

( if its possible ) ..

I have big project in same solution. 
Each project need to include same 3rd party lib X:

- `project1` include `lib X` =>  the output is `proj1.lib`
- `project2` include `lib X` and `proj1.lib` =>  the output is `proj2.lib`
- `project3` include `lib X` and `proj2.lib` and `proj1.lib` =>  the output is `proj3.exe`

Now, when I compile `project3` I get a warning about some function on lib X that already defined in `proj1.lib` and `proj2.lib` and redefined in `proj3.exe`

I'm trying to find a way to disable those warning.

Comment: It shouldn't be a warning, but an *error*. And the error is solved by changing the names of your symbols, or placing them in uniquely named namespaces.

Comment: i can't change it .. this is 3rd party lib that i dont have the code

Comment: You are using the library incorrectly. Your resulting program can get crashes and strange behaviour, You need to start using the library correctly, rather than disable the warnings. The correct way is to separate it into its own project in the solution, or perhaps even create an entirely separate solution for it.

Comment: Do your projects have different namespaces?

Comment: Don't 'include the lib' in project1 and project 2. Sure projects 1 and 2 need to reference the header files from your 3rd party but they don't need the lib itself.

Comment: @Galik no .. all my code is in the same namespace

Comment: @Yanshof could you please give us the exact message that you receive, and can you confirm that "including lib X" means for you to use `X.lib` and not to `#include` some files in the source code ?

Comment: `lib X` should be linked only to `proj3.exe`, on the other hand, if `lib X` is a header-only library that can be included indeed then there should be no warnings.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]